# Implementing onCreateOptionsMenu outside main activity class

Tags: android, menu

I have a UIManager class that I want to manage all user interaction, including the menu.

I have the menu working fine with this code:

```
    @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
    MenuItem payloadItem = (MenuItem) menu.findItem(R.id.payloadDisplayChoice);
    payloadItem.setTitle("Show L3 payload");
    return true;
}
```

but I would like to implement this code in the UIManager class.  The UIManager has a reference to the Activity and the baseContext, but when I put this code in the UIManager class it isn't recognized.

Any suggestions on what to do to enable this code to work outside the main Activity?

Thanks - moticon

Answer (score 0):

You can't just put `onCreateOptionsMenu` method in your UIManager class, because it belongs to Activity class.

However, you can create reference to your UIManager class in your activity and then create method that will halndle `onCreateOptionsMenu` (in UIManager). For example (in Activity class):

```
private UIManager manager=new UIManager(); //your UIManager reference

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
    return manager.handleOnCreateOptionsMenu(); //method of UIManager, that handles your onCreateOptionsMenu
}
```

Comment: That's a reasonable work-around.  I was hoping to eliminate all UI code from the main activity, but this cuts it down quite a bit.  Thanks for the idea.